# Calculating permutations using a Java annotation

Tags: java, math, annotations, permutation

I'm interested in calculating permutations for parameters for something like this:

```
public class Movie() {

   @Selection(minimum=1,maximum=10)
   public Integer setLength() {}

   @Selection(minimum=1.1,maximum=5.5)
   public Double setCost() {}

}
```

So I can write something like List getPermutations(); so that I could get a list of every movie possible.  I'm interested in supporting multiple data types.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to take on building the annotation and List getPermutations() method?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. To me it looks like you want to do a database query on existing movies. The mathematical meaning of permutation doesn't make sense in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.praeclarum.org/2006/04/knuths-solution-to-permutation-problem.html) an implementation of Donald Knuth's solution in C# that might be easy to port.